# Line breaks in MATLAB strings

Tags: string, matlab, line-breaks

I am writing a code in which I am asking the user for an input.  However the string informing the user about this is somewhat long, and when I use the code, it all gets written on a single line in the command window.  I would like to have this spread over multiple lines.  My code is:

```
n = input(['The matrix is diagonally dominant.  Please choose which method you wish to'...
        ' use: 1 (Gaussian elimination), 2 (Jacobi iterations),'...
        ' 3 (Gauss-Seidel iterations).  If you enter any other number'...
        ' Gaussian elimination will automatically be used: ']);
```

If preferable, I would like to have this displayed over 4 lines, as in the code.  How can I go about getting this done?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

use sprinf and \n (newline character)

```
n = input(sprintf(['The matrix is diagonally dominant.  Please choose which method you wish to\n'...
    ' use: 1 (Gaussian elimination), 2 (Jacobi iterations),\n'...
    ' 3 (Gauss-Seidel iterations).  If you enter any other number\n'...
    ' Gaussian elimination will automatically be used: ']));
```

Answer (score 7):

Use `\n` as an break character, for example:

```
n = input(sprintf('blablabla\nblablabla\n'))
```